# What do the authors mean by this, regarding estimation of mutual information

Tags: entropy, mutual-information

I found the following while reading a paper [1] and got confused:

> Replacing $k_{ij}$, $k{i.}$, respectively $k_{.j}$, by $k_{i,j}$, $k_{i.}$ and $k_{.j}$ provides us with estimates of entropy and mutual information.

This is on page 235, right after equation 2.9. The authors seemed to write about replacing the set of variables with another, but there seems to be a typo. It might not be a big deal but I don't want to miss something important here. Does anyone know what might be going on that paragraph?

#### References

[1] ON ESTIMATION OF ENTROPY AND MUTUAL INFORMATION OF
CONTINUOUS DISTRIBUTIONS https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11473936.pdf

Comment: You haven't reproduced the equations properly.  A *very* close look at the paper reveals a truly horrible notation in which underlines, overlines, and *extremely* subtle font differences (the first three instances of $k$ are rendered in a serif font but the last three are in a sans-serif font!) appear to be used in essential ways -- and many of those typographical differences are so subtle that they do not appear to be consistently rendered.  But in the context isn't the meaning clear? Parameters in a formula are replaced by their data-based estimates.  That's all.

Comment: I did not spot that, thanks. I am only reading these because I am searching if there is a method that can be used to estimate bivariate density with assuming independence. But the method the authors were showing did not seem that much different from KDE at the end.